# JavaScript regex - check number of numeric-only matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex thanks to another [wonderful StackOverflow user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5628/prestaul)

```
/(?:-\d+)*/g
```

I want it to match things like

```
133-134-454-58819860
12-13-876-1234346
```

each block (numbers between -'s) could be any length but it will defiantly only be numbers and there will only 4 blocks.

But currently it's matching things like -2008

I'm really bad at regex and I'm struggling, please help. I'm in JavaScript if that's helpful.

Comment: if you want to get better with RegEx's, a free tool like Expresso or the Regulator is very helpful...

Comment: Thanks Mitch. I've been using RegExr but I'll check that one out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

/(?:\d+-){3}\d+/

Comment: Ah that's how you do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
/(?:-\d+)*/g
```

breaks down into:

```
/    about to begin a regex

(    the following is a group

?:   but don't bother storing what this group finds as its own result

-    it must have a dash

\d   followed by digit(s)...

+    at least one digit, perhaps more

)    Im done with the group

*    But get me as many groups like that as you could

/    done with the regex
```

So it will find all groups like this -0000
but not like this -000-000

While writing this, other faster users published their own regexs.  But Im still posting so you follow the logic.

Comment: Great little tutorial. Regex is never explained like that. I don't know why. It's so much simpler

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match **exactly** four hyphen-separated numeric strings, you would want this:

```
/^\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+$/
```

The ^ and $ are anchors to constrain the match to the very beginning and very end of the string. You'll want to remove those if you are looking in a string with other text (e.g. "blah blah 12-12-12-12 blah blah").

Answer (score 0):

As far as checking the number of matches, the following should work:

```
alert(
  "133-134-454-58819860".match(/^(\d+-){3}\d+$/g).join("\n")
 );
```

The match function of JavaScript strings takes a regular expression object as a parameter.  It returns an array of matches, in the order in which they were found within the string.